# Filtering Google Places API results by keyword

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I would like to filter Google Places API results by keyword. It currently support the type "gym" but I want to get more specific such as "yoga" or "boxing". How do I implement this in my code?

```
function search() {
  var search = {
    bounds: map.getBounds(),
    types: ['gym']
  };


    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) can't go that much deeper/defined as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add the specific term as the `keyword` (assuming this is a Nearby Search request, for Text Search add it to the `query`):

```
var search = {
  keyword: 'boxing',
  bounds: map.getBounds(),
  types: ['gym']
};
```